# Hide sheet at the click of a button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've run into another roadblock.
I am simply trying to create a script to map to a button to hide the current sheet the button is being clicked.
That way user doesn't have to right click tab to hide the sheet.
I have tried the following

```
function hideSheet() {
  sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().hideSheet();
}
```

Cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function hideActiveSheet() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` is the same as `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`, they return a Class Spreadsheet object, in other words, these methods returns a spreadsheet also called workbook, not a sheet.

Instead use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` which returns a sheet.